# Prove that: $\vdash \forall x(\forall y\alpha)\to \forall y(\forall x \alpha)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

How does one prove that

> $$\vdash \forall x(\forall y\alpha)\to \forall y(\forall x \alpha)$$

in first order logic?

I have tried using the specialization and generalization rules on various wffs but they don't lead me to anything concrete.

Comment: Do $x$ or $y$ occur (unbound) in $\alpha$?  On the left, is $y$ dependent on or independent of $x$ and the analogous question on the right?

Comment: That is what troubles me. I can say something only if x and y are free in α.

Comment: See [interchange-quantifiers-using-the-generalization-theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831751/interchange-quantifiers-using-the-generalization-theorem) for a proof.

Comment: @Apurv - of course not; if $x$ is not free in $\alpha$, then $\forall x \alpha \equiv \alpha$, and thus swapping the quantifiers does not cause problems.

Comment: So the swap is not possible if x and y are free in alpha, right? Coz you have used that x and y are not free in alpha. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: @Apurv - NO; please, review the answer and the comment attached; nowhere in the proof restrictions on $x$ and $y$ are used. And this is consistent with the answer below: the formula is *valid*, and thus (by Completeness: $\vDash$ **iff** $\vdash$) it is *provable*.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a formula like $\forall x \forall y\ \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is another arbitrary formula, then we can exchange the order of the quantifiers without changing its semantics. Note, however, that this would NOT be possible if the quantifiers were different, e.g. $\forall x \exists y$.

Now why can we do this? Well, if we have a look at how the semantics of classical first-order logic are defined, then this becomes pretty obvious. Let's suppose we wish to evaluate the truth value of the formula for some signature $\Sigma$ over the domain $\mathcal{U}$ and a variable assignment $\gamma$. Furthermore, let's call the truth evaluation function $I$. With this we have
$$I_{\Sigma, \gamma} ( \forall x \forall y\ \alpha ) = \mathbf{T}$$
$$\iff I_{\Sigma, \gamma \cup \{ x \gets c \}} ( \forall y\ \alpha ) = \mathbf{T} \text{ for each $c \in \mathcal{U}$}$$
$$\iff I_{\Sigma, \gamma \cup \{ x \gets c, y \gets d \}} ( \alpha ) = \mathbf{T} \text{ for each $c , d \in \mathcal{U}$.}$$
Obviously, it makes no difference in which order these two quantifiers occur.

Therefore we observe that
$$
\forall x \forall y\ \alpha \to \forall y \forall x\ \alpha
\equiv \forall x \forall y\ \alpha \to \forall x \forall y\ \alpha
\equiv
$$
$$
\equiv \neg \forall x \forall y\ \alpha \lor \forall x \forall y\ \alpha
\equiv \top
\text{,}
$$
thus the formula is valid.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using the specialization and generalization rules on various wffs but they don't lead me to anything concrete.

They should.

Just assume $\forall x~(\forall y~\alpha)$, instantiate using fresh arbitrary variables, and generalise in reverse order to derive $\forall y~(\forall x~\alpha)~$, under that assumption.

Now you may deduce $(\forall x~(\forall y~\alpha))\to(\forall y~(\forall x~\alpha))$.

$\blacksquare$